# how to change the value of jqPlot lineLabels

Tags: javascript, jqplot, pie-chart

I am trying to draw a PIE using jqPlot.
I am using the property of lineLabels to show a label with line outside the PIE.

The problem is that the value of these labels is: (for example) Overdue(34%)

Instead i want this to show Overdue(42).

42 is the value of the field, and not the percentage.

Please help me, i have searched the internet everywhere.

This is my code:

```
var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot (graphContainerId, [data], {
    gridPadding: {top:0, bottom:0, left:50, right:50},
    seriesColors: COLOURS_ARRAY,
    seriesDefaults:{
        shadow:false, 
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        animation: false,
        renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: { 
            startAngle: -90,
            padding:50, 
            paddingColor:'#FFFFFF',
            lineLabels: true, 
            lineLabelsLineColor: '#777',
                            showDataLabels: true,
            dataLabels: 'value',
        }
    },

    legend: { show:false},
}
```

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pabloker/wMy5v/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = [['A',40],['B',25],['C',35],['D',90]];
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [data], {
gridPadding: {top:0, bottom:0, left:50, right:50},
seriesDefaults:{
    shadow:false, 
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    animation: false,
    renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
    rendererOptions: { 
        startAngle: -90,
        padding:50, 
        paddingColor:'#FFFFFF',
        lineLabels: true, 
        lineLabelsLineColor: '#777',
        showDataLabels: true,
        dataLabels: data,
        dataLabelNudge: 70
    }
},
legend: { show:false}
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pabloker/wMy5v/3/